# Homology of the dg-nerve vs Hochschild homology of the dg-category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, ct.category-theory

Lurie in Higher Algebra, section 1.3 associates a quasi-category to a dg-category A via the so called dg-nerve construction, extending the classical nerve. I have a feeling the homology of the geometric realization of this quasi-category (in particular a simplicial set) should be related to Hochschild homology of A. Is anything known about this?

Comment: Have you at least thought whether the coefficients for both homologies could be the same kind of object?

Comment: The negative Hochschild cohomology groups are realized as homotopy groups of the classifying space ($\infty$-groupoid) of dg categories. See Corollary 8.5 of Toen's The homotopy theory of dg categories and derived Morita theory.

Comment: @Chris, I think Yasha asks about $HH_\ast(C)$, not $HH^\ast$. Yasha, I see more naturally a relationship between $HH_\ast$ and the homotopy groups of the (free loop space of the) geometric realization; if you want to relate it to homology, you probably want some Hurewicz type assumption on the nerve of the category. Dually, the result Chris cites is fairly intuitive--$HH^\ast$ is endomorphisms of the identity of $C$, so you can see it at the $\pi_2$ level of the (largest) oo-groupoid contained in the oo-category of dg-categories, with basepoint $C$.

Comment: @Fernando, I mean of course $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients for homology. Both are naturally Z modules if you wish :)
@Hiro, thanks I also realized later by looking at a very specific example that one should instead consider the free loop space of the geometric realization. Although I am not yet convinced on homotopy groups vs homology groups, in the example I was considering it didn't matter as the realization of the dg-nerve had the homotopy type of the circle. If there is demand I can add this example to the body of question.

Comment: @yasha what's Hochschild homology of a dg-category with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Fernando I meant $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients for homology of the loop space. The question is simply about relating a pair of naturally appearing Abelian groups, so I don't understand your objection. 

Comment: @yasha, I have no objection, I had just a question, so far unanswered.

Comment: @Fernando What does your question have to do with price of tea in China? I never mentioned $Z$ coefficients for Hochschild homology. I was talking about the plain old Hochschild homology.

Comment: @yasha, my unanswered question is in my first comment... The 'plain old Hochschild homology' has certain coefficients, as you probably know: bimodules. In general, I don't see how to relate two (co)homology theories unless they have the same kind of objects as coefficients. I wonder whether you have an idea about the two ones you want to relate. For your reaction, it seems like if I were asking about something very strange, but I think it's a pretty obvious question.